# Strange Intellisense errors on React Connected Component in VS2017

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, visual-studio-2017, react-redux

I'm pulling [this](https://github.com/DimitriMikadze/node-redux-auth/blob/master/client/src/app/components/auth/SignupVerify.jsx) .jsx connected component into my React-Redux project as a .js file, and am getting strange errors which I'm not getting on any of my other components.

For instance, the class name here is grayed out and a message appears saying "local variable SignupVerify is never used", even though I'm exporting SignupVerify below as a connected component.

```
class SignupVerify extends Component
{..}
```

Then, in my export statement, the closing semicolon is throwing an error: "} expected":

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(SignupVerify);
```

I've checked-all my brackets are closed in the appropriate places and Intellisense recognizes it.

It's also throwing me errors here:

```
function mapStateToProps(state){
        return {
            errorMessage: state.auth.error,
            signup: state.auth.signup 
    }
}
```

Telling me that it expects me to close the first curly bracket.

In the error list console, I see ESLint:Component Definition is Missing Display Name.

Anyone have a clue what's behind all this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with your code. For me the Intellisense works perfectly fine. I guess though that you have an ESLint setting that forces you to define a **[displayName](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#displayname)** for your component.

React's virtual DOM works with displaynames to name components with. You can see these display names within the React Developer tools in Chrome.

Try doing this:

```
class SignupVerify extends Component {
  static displayName = 'SignupVerify';

  constructor(props) {
  ...
```

or under your class definition

```
SignupVerify.displayName = 'SignupVerify';
```

Comment: I thought that might be the issue as well, but it doesn't solve the problem; not only that, but I have other components which are very similar, have no display name set, yet throw no errors.

Comment: But is the application not compiling? Or is it just an Intellisense issue. I've had issues like this before with VSCode, restarting the application helped for me.

Comment: The application compiles; it seems to be an intellisense issue.

Comment: Have you tried to just type the code over in steps? Just make a component that renders a div, then add the lifecycles, etc.